# Android Studio -> How to Switch a project between Library project and Application project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, library-project

i'm migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio and i am facing this problem:

In Eclipse i have a Library project A (`library`) and a Application project B (`launcher`).

My `launcher` project, has a reference to my `library` project. My `library` project has all the logic with a lot of activities, resources etc... and a dummy `AndroidManifest.xml` file that it is an copy of my `launcher` manifest but with renamed packages to make it compatible. When i want to test the logic of my `Library` project in Eclipse, i simply unmark "library" checkbox in project configuration tab in eclipse. As my `library` project has a `AndroidManifest.xml`, it can be executed if i unmark that checkbox.

Now i'm trying to achieve the same in AndroidStudio but i am facing a problem. I don't know how to switch easily a project to change between application project and library project, and also AndroidStudio it is giving me a lot of errors because it detect duplicated items between my `library` project `AndroidManifest.xml` and my `launcher` project `AndroidManifest.xml` when I try to compile my `launcher` project referencing my `library` project...

Any help will be grated..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say that in the build.gradle file you can specify if the module is an app or a library

If the module is an app you must specify

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

If it's a library

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Comment: yes but i still have the duplicate errors between the manifest files, please read the last part of my question

Answer (score 0):

Remove lib's dependence before change your build.gradle.

> compile project('xxx')